# i can't get email from facebook auth login

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, facebook-login

i try login with facebook auth login 
i can access user all data but user email not show

i have used this code in codeigniter controller

```html
include_once APPPATH."libraries/facebook-api-php-codexworld/facebook.php";
  
  // Facebook API Configuration
  $appId = '307082112994945';
  $appSecret = '92ff6f98cc08c777c952fd79b1f1a396';
  $redirectUrl = base_url() . 'auth-facebook/';
  $fbPermissions = 'email';
  
  //Call Facebook API
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $appSecret
  
  ));
  $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
  
        if ($fbuser) {
            
   $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,updated_time,picture');
            // Preparing data for database insertion
   $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
   $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
            $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
            $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
   $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
   $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
                        $userData['updated_time'] = $userProfile['updated_time'];
                        
            $userData['profile_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$userProfile['id'];
            $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture']['data']['url'];
```

Comment: stackoverflow is full of threads about that, you should do some research. it can be the access token, it can be that the user does not have an email, ...

Comment: if fb user set visibility to private then it won't be there in response